# jQuery datatable retain row highlight after reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I am reloading my datatable on 10 second intervals.  When a user clicks on a row, that row will highlight.  But when the datatable reloads, the highlight is gone.

Here is the shortened code for my datable:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  // set datatable
  $('#example1').DataTable({        
    "ajax": {
      "url": "api/process.php",
      "type": "POST",
      "dataSrc": ''
    },
    "columns": [
      { "data": "" },
      { "data": "column1" },
      { "data": "column2" },
      { "data": "column3" }
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "order": [[ 6, "desc" ]],
    "scrollY": 600,
    "scrollX": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "stateSave": true
  });

  // reload datatable every 30 seconds
  setInterval(function()
  {
    var table = $('#example1').DataTable();
    table.ajax.reload();
  }, 30000);

  // highlight row
  $('#example1 tbody').on('click', 'tr', function()
  {
    $('#example1 tbody > tr').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

All of the above works exactly how it's supposed to work.  I just need to retain the row highlight after the datatable reloads.

Also, I attempted the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32436150/jquery-datatable-highlight-drops-off-after-reload), but I scrapped it as the row no longer highlights.

Comment: Can you add a working fiddle. I think I can help you if I get working fiddle ...

Comment: Please explain why are you removing and adding 'selected' class in using two different selectors $('#example1 tbody > tr').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

Comment: which row you want to highlight, Any specific row?  I cannot see anything happening on any row click other then playing with classes?  Ajax call is happening irrespective of any row clicked.

Comment: @amitwadhwani - The user can click a row, and the row highlights.  When the datatable reloads, that same row should remain highlighted.

Comment: There is nothing to identify individual rows. At least you must have some unique row numbers or ids.

Comment: Please find my answer below, I have saved row clicked in global parameter and then focussed the clicked row

Answer (score 2):

Kindly update js file with below changes. Below code will save row clicked in global parameter and then focus the clicked row after ajax call.

```
var gblIndex = 0; //this will save row clicked index

function setFocus(){ 
$($('#example1 tbody > tr')[gblIndex]).addClass('selected');  

}


$(document).ready(function() 
{
  // set datatable
  $('#example1').DataTable({        
    "ajax": {
      "url": "api/process.php",
      "type": "POST",
      "dataSrc": ''
    },
    "columns": [
      { "data": "" },
      { "data": "column1" },
      { "data": "column2" },
      { "data": "column3" }
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "order": [[ 6, "desc" ]],
    "scrollY": 600,
    "scrollX": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "stateSave": true
  });

  // reload datatable every 30 seconds
  setInterval(function()
  {
    var table = $('#example1').DataTable();
    table.ajax.reload();
    setFocus(); // this will set focus/highlight row
  }, 30000);

  // highlight row
  $('#example1 tbody').on('click', 'tr', function()
  {
    $('#example1 tbody > tr').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    gblIndex = $(this).index(); // this will save the index clicked
  });
});
```

Comment: I get the following error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ which is pointing at the [gblIndex ] in the function setFocus().

Comment: please remove the space [gblIndex ] and check

Comment: Removed the space, but still getting the same error.

Comment: `index()` is redefined for each reload. You will select the same indexes, but probably not the same rows. I guess there is a pretty good reason for reloading the table, i.e rows will change :)

Comment: Thanks to all who took the time to help me.  I will just abandon the highlight on reload.  Upvotes for all.

Comment: I have updated the code, Apology as there was typo in earlier code, Now used proper syntax $($('#example1 tbody > tr')[gblIndex ]).addClass('selected');

Comment: @amitwadhwani - I attempted your last update, it appeared to work at first.  I did not get any errors, and the row stayed highlighted after the table reloaded, but after the table uploaded again, the highlight disappeared.

Comment: can you please check  what is the value in gblIndex after second reload, It should not get change and it should be non zero. Please check and let me know

Comment: @amitwadhwani - gblIndex was 2

Comment: @amitwadhwani - interesting...I had clicked on the 3rd row, and the gblIndex was 2.  I clicked on the first row, and the gblIndex was 0.  Any thoughts?

Comment: It starts from 0, If you click 1 st row index will be 0, If you click 2 nd row then index will be 1 and so on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151903/discussion-between-amit-wadhwani-and-john-beasley).

Comment: $($('#example1 tbody > tr')[gblIndex]).delay(1000).addClass('selected'); Kindly try this

Comment: @amitwadhwani - Sorry...the last addition was unsuccessful.

Answer (score -1):

You should review their actual selection documentation to manipulate this. This feature is already built in and setup so on ajax.reload() it will keep your selections.

You can apply classes/styling with their methods as well.

> https://datatables.net/reference/option/#select

Comment: I think what Blake is trying to say is that when initializing jquery DataTables there is a `rowId` option that represents the field in your data that maintains a unique identifier for each row. Based on their [documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/reload.html) they should maintain the selection through reloads.